# Mod rewrite problem - Url/path can be entered twice

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have found an Problem in my web application using `mod rewrite` and `URL rewriting`.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^blog myblogfile.php [L]
```

But if i enter in Browser the url: `mydomain.com/blog/blog` it works also but the `myblogfile.php` file display without images and stylesheet (Wrong Path).

But why is it possible to enter it twice and see the same Page as only `mydomain.com/blog`?
I want see my "Not found" Page.

Its also an security issue , because force SSL dont work on this Path and its insecure.

I have also other multilanguage folders with own .htaccess files (All has the same) but other

```
RewriteBase /en
```

Maybe this the Problem? Never see it before that i can enter twice the path and rewrite works.

Thanks!

Comment: It is possible, because the pattern `^blog` is only anchored at the beginning - this matches everything that _starts with_ `blog`, no matter what comes after. `blogwrgelglupps` would currently also work with your rule there. If you don’t want that - well then you need to be more specific in that place.

Comment: What you need for Infos? I only want allow the path: `mydomain.com/blog` nothing other

Comment: Well then anchor the pattern at the end as well - using a `$`.

Comment: You mean : `RewriteRule ^blog myblogfile.php$ [L] ?` ?

Comment: Only on the regex pattern, not on the substitution part.

Comment: Edit my comment, right?

Comment: No. `^blog$`. The target URL has to stay as it is, you don’t want to redirect to `myblogfile.php$`

Comment: Oh yes that works:) Sorry and Thanks, helped me a lot!